# Rails 3.1: undefined sortable_element using acts_as_list gem - how to fix?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, ruby-on-rails-3.1, acts-as-list

How do I get sortable_element from the acts_as_list gem to work nice with Rails 3.1?  I think it's because jquery is used instead of prototype so I lose that helper method?  Is this right?  In which case does that mean I need to use jrails (and how best to do this in Rails 3.1)?

Comment: Found this article which seems to be a working solution: http://awesomeful.net/posts/47-sortable-lists-with-jquery-in-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you've moved to Rails 3.1 and you're just using acts_as_list as a way to give yourself nice ajax-y moveable lists - up and down - then you might be better off, as I've just done, following the great little walkthrough here http://practiceovertheory.com/blog/2009/08/06/sortable-lists-with-jquery-in-rails/ and ditching the gem.

Comment: Hey Richard, this looks exactly like the type of info I wanted to look up but the link does not go anywhere. Do you know where is that resource now? I need it badly!!!

Comment: do you want to try it again - i just clicked on http://practiceovertheory.com/blog/2009/08/07/sortable-lists-with-jquery-in-rails/ and it worked... i know it sounds dumb but do you just wanna try it again or copy the link into google

Comment: It works now. I tried for at least 24 hours before and it was broken. Good point about Google cache. Did not even think about it! duh